# Complex regex matching query?

Tags: php, regex

Task is to determine a key string which should satisfy the condition `strpos( $key, 'R_4r3@')!== FALSE` and simultaneously satisfy the regex condition `/^-?[a-z0-9]+$/m` and printing success as output.

Question Source Code:

```
<?php

$key=$_POST['key'];
if (strpos( $key, 'R_4r3@')!== FALSE){
    if (!preg_match('/^-?[a-z0-9]+$/m', $key)) {
        die('ILLEGAL CHARACTERS');
    }
echo 'success';
} else {
    echo 'Wrong Password';
} ?>
```

Attempts at solution:

`-?` means key can contain `-` 0 or 1 time at the beginning of the key.
`[a-z0-9]+` all lowercase letters and numbers occur 1 or more times.
`$` element determined in the previous case should be the last element.
Possible escaping of condition might be required, but don't know how to proceed.

Comment: so what is the issue?

Comment: What, exactly, is your question?

Comment: `R_4r3@` can never match `^-?[a-z0-9]+$`...

Comment: it should be like `^-?[a-zA-Zz0-9_@]+`

Comment: @don'tangryme the question is to determine a key string that satisfies above two conditions.

Comment: @SujithSizon I've added an answer for you but it `R_4r3@` will never match with this regex `^-?[a-z0-9]+$`, you've to modify it. Have a look on my answer. Let me know if anything else I missed away

Comment: @don'tangryme The question cant be changed its hosted on my mentor's server, I have to find the key string that satisfies two conditions. Im trying to use escaping tactics to escape the first check but im not able to get very far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key `-a2c\nR_4r3@` solves your problem.

- `strpos` returns TRUE because `R_4r3@` exists in the key
- `preg_match` returns TRUE because the first line contains only alphanum

---

```
$key = "-a2c\nR_4r3@";
if (strpos( $key, 'R_4r3@')!== FALSE){
    if (!preg_match('/^-?[a-z0-9]+$/m', $key)) {
        die('ILLEGAL CHARACTERS');
    }
    echo 'success';
} else {
    echo 'Wrong Password';
}
```

**Output:**

```
success
```

Comment: nice catch though for me \n didnt work so used %0A instead